# How to avoid my permutation algorithm of ERROR:heap out memory

Tags: javascript, node.js

Today I try to solve a problem on [codewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/simple-fun-number-159-middle-permutation/train/javascript)，it requires me give the permutations of a given string.

Firstly,I try to use a recursion function looks like:

```
function permutate(str) {

    var result = [];
    if (str.length == 1) {
        return [str]
    } else {

        var preResult = permutate(str.slice(1));
        for (var j = 0; j < preResult.length; j++) {
            for (var k = 0; k < preResult[j].length + 1; k++) {
                var temp = preResult[j].slice(0, k) + str[0] + preResult[j].slice(k);
                result.push(temp);
            }
        }
        return result;

    }
}
```

After I click the attemp button,the OJ tells me there is an error caused by heap out memory.Because my function called with a long string:"abcdefghijkl".

Secondly,I rewrite my function by using loop.just like:

```
function perm(str) {
    let result = [],tempArr = [];
    let subStr = str;
    while (subStr.length !== 0) {
        if (result.length === 0) {
            result.push(str[0]);
        } else {
            for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                let item = result[i];
                let itemLen = item.length;
                for (let j = 0; j < itemLen+1; j++) {

                    let temp = item.slice(0, j) + subStr[0] + item.slice(j);
                    tempArr.push(temp);
                }
            }
            result = tempArr;
            tempArr = [];
        }
        subStr = subStr.slice(1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

It works when the given string is short.But still cause Error.

So,I want to know why cause this error and if there is a permutation algorithm can run in Node(v6.11.0) without memory error?

I searched a lot and tried many methods,but nothing works.So I ask my first question on stackoverflow,hoping you can give me some help.Thanks!

Comment: The number of permutations for a string of length 12 is 479001600. Multiply that by atleast 12 (the length of each string) and you get 5748019200 bytes of memory required to store all those strings in `tempArr`. That's a lot of memory.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen That's right.So I really want to know how to decrease the space complexity？Or it's actually impossible,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the module https://github.com/miguelmota/permutations, or even try to use the code from the module

Comment: This module is the same as my first code above,so when i call it with the string "abcdefghij",it's doesn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to previous answer as a possible try out, you can try to increase process max memory limit size, for example with `node --max-old-space-size=8192` which is in bytes, the node process will run with extended 8GB memory limit.

Comment: I know this command,it really works.But I can't increase the memory on codewars.